# From multiples CSV to Dataframe columns with calculs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I got 10 csvfiles like this :

[image: Text]

I want to add 10 columns in my dataframe with a vwap calculation. I tried to create the columns and then to concatenate it into the dataframe but it doesn't work at all. I tried a lot of things, the main problem is that i can't create new columns with calculated rows :

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import csv
# use glob to get all the csv files 
# in the folder

path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join("*.csv"))

""" 
#To change the name of every columns
liste1 = []
header_list = []
for f in csv_files:
    liste1.append(f)
header_list = [a.strip(".csv") for a in liste1]
 """
def add(f):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
    df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
    df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = "timestamp", freq = "h")).agg("mean").reset_index()
    price = df["price"]
    amount = df["amount"]
    return df.assign(vwap  = (price * amount).cumsum() / amount.cumsum())

for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
    df2 = pd.concat(add(f))
    df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Sorbonne\resultat\resultat_projet_4.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False, mode = "a")
```

Thanks for your help

The traceback :

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16732/557098648.py in <module>
     31 for f in csv_files:
     32     df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
---> 33     df2 = pd.concat(add(f))
     34     df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Sorbonne\resultat\resultat_projet_4.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False, mode = "a")
     35 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    292     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    293     """
--> 294     op = _Concatenator(
    295         objs,
    296         axis=axis,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    327     ):
    328         if isinstance(objs, (ABCSeries, ABCDataFrame, str)):
--> 329             raise TypeError(
    330                 "first argument must be an iterable of pandas "
    331                 f'objects, you passed an object of type "{type(objs).__name__}"'

TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Comment: Define *"doesn't work at all"*. Be specific.

Comment: Right. In this code i got the error : TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame". But i tried a lot of things, the main problem is that i can't create new columns with calculated rows

Comment: Please add the *full* traceback into the question.

Comment: I added it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need only aggregate values in ouput:

```
def add(df):
    #Removed read_csv 
    df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
    df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = "timestamp", freq = "h")).agg("mean").reset_index()
    price = df["price"]
    amount = df["amount"]
    return (price * amount).cumsum() / amount.cumsum()

out = []
for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
    #added aggregate DataFrame with new column to list of DataFrames
    out.append(add(df))
    
#joined all dfs together
df2 = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True, axis=1)  
#removed append mode
df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Sorbonne\resultat\resultat_projet_4.csv", 
             encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: The second one is nice. It does the aggregate but it doesn't create new columns for every csvfiles. But it's helping me a lot anyway, thanks

Comment: @SRP - `it doesn't create new columns for every csvfiles. `  So it means code `df.assign(vwap  = (price * amount).cumsum() / amount.cumsum())` in function `def add(df):` not working? Not undertastand

Comment: The result i get : https://i.imgur.com/rNZJ4la.png

This is nice but as you can see the second csv (and all csv after) are below the first, i want only the "vwap columns" for every csv. One columns = one result of one csv

Comment: @SRP - Can you check edited answer - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69404922/revisions) ?

Comment: It does not create new columns. But i don't see anymore the header of every csv, the result are : https://i.imgur.com/OeqbdAR.png

Comment: @SRP - hmm, is your code like `out.append(add(df))` ?

Comment: @SRP - hmm, I see new column vwap in i.imgur.com/OeqbdAR.png

Comment: Yes but only one. We got one column for all csv. To be more specific, i have to show for every hours of the day, a vwap value for every exchange (one exchange = one csv). 

So i have to add a column for every csv. I'm sorry if it's unclear my english is pretty bad

Comment: @SRP - We got one column for all csv.  yes, it is expected. Each file has one new column and if join all together big file has one new column. Something not understand?

Comment: What i try to build is more something like this : https://i.imgur.com/wTLaXOV.png

Comment: @SRP - Answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks man. I don't know how it's so easy for you to modify the code like that. The timestamp disapear in the process but i think i will figure out how to put it in. Thanks again

Comment: @SRP - Use `df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Sorbonne\resultat\resultat_projet_4.csv", 
             encoding='utf-8')` remove `index=False`